# Code preventing app from opening?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, split

Is my code preventing my app from opening? There are no errors, however it is not opening. Or is there problems with the split string that is causing conflict somewhere?

**Mainactivity:**

```
package com.pk.code;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView smsText;@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        smsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smsText);

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extra != null) {
            String SMSText = extra.get("sms").toString();
            String[] splitted = SMSText.split("-");
            if (splitted.length > 1 && splitted.length < 4) {
                smsText.setText(" " + splitted[0] + "," + " " + splitted[1]);
            } else {
                smsText.setText(SMSText);


            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to open it and what happens exactly?

Comment: What does logcat logs?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem in extra.get("sms") , it returns null . Check your logcat and print it here after crashing